# Software to filter audio output for static in real-time

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, audio, real-time

I am looking for software that is able to filter out static from an output device in real-time. A specific application that I am using randomly outputs loud static in the form of white noise or otherwise.

I have decided to ask a Q&A forum for help on this matter due to the volume of search results on the internet being relating to fixing static that is caused by interference.

Feature requirements

1. Must run on Windows
2. Perfer FOSS, or at least it being free (as in no money) software
3. Perfer stable software, no buggy software
4. Best if software takes up minimal system resources (no more than 100 MB of ram should be used)
5. Best if software takes less than 50 MB of storage

As a side note, the specific problem I am having is Cemu (a console emulation program) not allowing for the optimization of disabling the hooking of static functions. On my CPU specifically, when there is the hooking of static functions, it will cause my audio devices to output audio artifacts. The specific model of my CPU is the A8-6600k.